# Browsers hang on Moodle site

Tags: 16.04, firefox, google-chrome, moodle

I work with moodle sites, and in one of them my browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Opera) stop working whenever I activate edit mode on Moodle. They just stay loading the page when I try to edit anything on the site, for a couple of minutes, after which they return to the home page.

This happens while running Ubuntu (I tested on Ubuntu, Lubuntu, Ubuntu Gnome, Linux Mint) but not on Windows, nor Fedora. Additionaly, this does not happen on browsers based on Webkit, at least not on Epiphany or Midori.

This particular site is on Moodle 2.9.5+ (Build: 20160317). All browsers are up to date.

So far I could only determine that this is a javascript related issue. But why does it affects only my browsers running on Ubuntu, I can`t tell.

Comment: can you please tell how to test.

Comment: Thankx for your comment. This is very specific and very hard to test, since it happens on a single moodle site, for which you would have to have administrator privileges to be able to test this.